# MySQL SELECT GROUP_CONCAT AND SUM

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have the following tables

**apps table**

```
--------------------------------
id | appointment_id | service_id
--------------------------------
1 | 258 | 4
2 | 258 | 5
--------------------------------
```

**services table**

```
--------------------------------
id | price
--------------------------------
4 | 10
5 | 20
--------------------------------
```

What I would like to do is to SELECT all service_id that belongs to appointment_id 258 from apps table and also get the SUM price for all services from services table.

I have seen that with GROUP_CONCAT I can get the service_id as a comma separated value but maybe will be better to use subqueries or inner join?

Comment: Please include your query attempts.

Comment: I have only done this so far: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(service_id) as servlist FROM apps WHERE appointment_id = '258'

Comment: Can you show us your exact expected output?

Comment: I just want to get the total price/sum so it should be: "30"

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT
    SUM(s.price) AS total_price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.id) AS service_ids
FROM services s
INNER JOIN apps a
    ON s.id = a.service_id
WHERE
    a.appointment_id = 258;
```

It is somewhat unusual to be using `GROUP_CONCAT` without `GROUP BY`, but perhaps this is your requirement.